# Is there way to extract the sections and notes from one note using web api

Tags: asp.net, synchronization, onenote

I am trying to write a sync program so that someone can link with one note from inside my asp.net application. I would like to read all the section names / page names from one note (via api) and show them on my application. I would also like to download the notes in html format so that users can preview. If they want to edit or add a new notes then I would like to send them to the one note web application to make changes.

I could not find an api for this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current APIs only allow you to create pages. We don't have support for reading pages, sections or notebooks back at the moment, but we are actively working on those APIs. Follow us on Twitter @onenotedev for future updates. We expect to make some of these APIs available over the next several months.